# Python, return variable from an function

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

Im trying to get the content of the var "key" with the return method :

```
key = b''

def encodingKey(password_provided):
  password = password_provided.encode()#Convertion de str a Bytes
  salt = os.urandom(16)
  kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
  algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
  length=32,
  salt=salt,
  iterations=100000,
  backend=default_backend()
  )
  key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))

  return key


encodingKey("123456")

print(key)
```

But here my output :

```
b''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to assign the return value of your function to the variable key. i.e

```
key = encodingKey("123456")
print(key)
```

Comment: Thank you, so obvious ^^